# Homework Help: Max and min value with if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, max, min

How is it possible, to get the min and max values for three numbers, with just three If statements (no else) and without any loops?
I have the following code, which gives me just the max value:

```
            max = a;
            min = a;

            if (b > max)
            {
                max = b;
            }
            if (c > max)
            {
                max = c;
            }
```

How can I get the min value with one more if statement?

Comment: Reminds me of the question. Swap two variables without using a third. Sure you can do it, but why write confusing code? Just use the 3rd variable.

Comment: Why, why, why?  C# has built-ins for this as does all languages.

using System;

using System.Linq;


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
 int[] array1 = { 1, -1, -2, 0 };

 // Find maximum number.
 Console.WriteLine(array1.Max());
    }
}

Comment: @JasonEnochs - one possibility is to learn how merge-sort works. It also may be a bit faster to inline min/max for small number of items (2-4)... but generally - no use outside homework/warm-up interview questions.

Comment: @JasonEnochs because it's a homework assignment :/. I wish homework assignments were banned here. Everybody spams them for the upvotes. Nobody learns, and these questions aren't applicable to anything people will ever google. They are polluting the airwaves and helping people through school without teaching them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int a = 10, b = 20, c=30;

int max = a, min = b;

if ( a < b )
{
    min = a;
    max = b;
}

if ( c < min )
   min = c;
if ( c > max )
   max = c;
```

It has exactly three logical if to determine the max and min. I hope this would help.

Comment: Nice you beat me to the punch but doesn't this seem like a homework assignment :)

Comment: I agree. Its definitely an assignment

Answer (score -2):

Are you allowed to use an `else`?

```
max = a;
min = a;

if (b > max)
{
    max = b;
}
else
{
    min = b;
}
if (c > max)
{
    max = c;
}
if (c < min)
{
    min = c;
}
```

Comment: he said that he is not allowed to use else

Comment: Good point, I completely missed that in the question. So much for reading carefully...